# jqGrid send data from one list to another

Tags: javascript, html

I am using JQuery JqGrid. What I am trying to do is to send data from one list to another. Data sends successfully ,but problem is all of the data displays in a single page and my first gird contain 7 pages...What should I do know?

Here is my code of javascript.

```
        jQuery().ready(function (){
            jQuery("#list1").jqGrid ({
                url: 'data.json',
                datatype: 'json',
                colNames: ['File' , 'UID' , 'Order' , 'Method' , 'Type' , 'Project' , 'Phase'],
                        colModel: [
                        {name: 'file' , index: 'file' , width: 140},
                        {name: 'uid' , index: 'uid' , width: 80},
                        {name: 'order' , index: 'order' , width: 60},
                        {name: 'method' , index: 'method' , width: 60 },
                        {name: 'type' , index: 'type' , width: 75 },
                        {name: 'project' , index: 'project' , width: 100 },
                        {name: 'phase' , index: 'phase' , width: 75}
                    ],
                    rowNum: 10,
                    autowidth: true,
                    rowList: [10 , 50 , 100],
                    pager: '#pager',
                    loadonce: true,
                    sortname: 'file',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    sortOrder: "asc",
                    toolbar: [true,"both"],
                    caption: 'JqGrid Examples'}).navGrid('#pager' , {edit:false , add:false, del:false});


            //$('<div><span id="myToolbar" style="float: right;"></span></div>').appendTo($("#tb_list1"));
            $('<button>', {title: 'Click me!'}).css({float: "right", height: "21px", width: "20px"
            }).appendTo("#tb_list1").button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-gear"
                },
                text: false
            }).click(function (e) {

                //var pageSize = $('#list1').getGridParam('rowNum');
                //$('#list1').setGridParam({ rowNum: 10000 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
                var data= $("#list1").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    jQuery("#list1_d").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,data[i]);
                }

            });


            jQuery("#list1_d").jqGrid ({
                //url: 'data.json',
                //datatype: 'json',
                colNames: ['File' , 'UID' , 'Order' , 'Method' , 'Type' , 'Project' , 'Phase'],
                        colModel: [
                        {name: 'file' , index: 'file' , width: 140},
                        {name: 'uid' , index: 'uid' , width: 80},
                        {name: 'order' , index: 'order' , width: 60},
                        {name: 'method' , index: 'method' , width: 60 },
                        {name: 'type' , index: 'type' , width: 75 },
                        {name: 'project' , index: 'project' , width: 100 },
                        {name: 'phase' , index: 'phase' , width: 75}
                    ],
                    //rowNum: 10,
                    autowidth: true,
                    //rowList: [10 , 50 , 100],
                    pager: '#pager_d',
                    sortname: 'file',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    sortOrder: "asc",
                    toolbar: [true,"both"],
                    caption: 'JqGrid Examples'}).navGrid('#pager_d' , {edit:false , add:false, del:false});



        });

    </script>
```